# No main methods, applets, or MIDlets found

Tags: java, jgrasp, main-method

When I run this a popup comes up telling me no main methods, applets, or MIDlets ound. Can someone tell me why please?--I am using jGrasp. I am trying to use main method and I haven't had this issue before.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class ProgrammingExercise3.1
{
   public static void main(String[] args);
   {

      double rectWidth;
      double rectLength;
      double radius;
      int age;
      double begBal;
      char A;
      String name;
      double rate;

      scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\sierr_000\\Desktop\\Sam School\\IT-145\\Exercises\\Ch 3\\inData.txt"));

      PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\sierr_000\\Desktop\\Sam School\\IT-145\\Exercises\\Ch 3\\outData.out");

      rectWidth = inFile.next();
      rectLength = inFile.next();

      outFile.println("Rectangle: ")
      outFile.println("Length = " + rectLength + ", width = " + rectWidth + ", area = "
                     + (rectWidth*rectLength) + ", perimeter = " + (2 * (rectwidth + rectLengh)));

      radius = inFile.next();

      outFile.println("Circle: ");
      outfile.println("Radius = " + radius + ", area = " + (radius*3.1416) + "Circumfrence = " + (2*3.1416*radius));

      name = inFile.next();
      age = inFile.next();
      begBal = inFile.next();
      rate = inFile.next();

      outFile.println("Name: " + name + ", age: " + age);
      outFile.printf("Beginning Balance: %7.2f" , begBal + "interest rate: %4.2f" , rate);
      outFile.println("The character that comes after A in the ASCII is B");      




      inFile.close();
      outFile.close();

   }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of `public static void main(String[] args);`. Also, I doubt that it likes the `.` in the class name `ProgrammingExercise3.1`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be full of errors, but the main reason you are getting that error is that you put a semicolon after `public static void main(String[] args)`.